# Unable to get property 'location' of undefined or null reference ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this file which is causing an error in my reactapp.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router'; 

import App from './components/App';
import About from './components/About'; 
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
    </Router>
);


export default Routes;
```

For some reason, if I replace

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
</Router>
```

with just a simple content like `<div> hi </div>` then I can see hi in my app, otherwise I get this error.

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'location' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your route structure, i am assuming you are using react-router V2 or V3.

You missed the history part with router use either `hashHistory` or `browerHistory` and define it like this:

```
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'

<Router history={hasHistory}>
   ....
</Router>
```

Check the **[DOC](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v2.8.1/docs/guides/Histories.md) for more details about history**.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are using react router V4.0, use v3.0.0 it will work.